# Google ADK 2012 - where to buy

Tags: android, adk

Does anybody know where I can buy the Google ADK 2012?

Thanks
Thomas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't but you can find some alternatives if you search Google for it.

Example: 
http://www.seeedstudio.com/depot/seeeduino-adk-main-board-p-846.html

From the developers site:

> A limited number of these kits were produced and distributed at the
>   Google I/O 2012 developer conference. If you did not receive one of
>   these kits, fear not! The specifications and design files for the
>   hardware were also released for use by manufacturers and hobbyists.
>   You should expect to see kits with similar features available for
>   purchase, or you can build one yourself!
>   http://developer.android.com/tools/adk/adk2.html

Note: This board is not compatible with ADK 2012, only the 2011 ADK.

Comment: thanks for the quick response. I know that its possible to build such a device and that there are many compatible boards out there. But there ADK 2012 that google shows up at google io looks really cool :-)